# how to make get request with headers in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, testing, get, request

My request:

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun shouldMeIfAccountExistsReturn200() {

   val account = accountService.createAccount(AccountSignUpForm("test6", "1234", "test7", false))
    val authorities = arrayListOf<String>()



    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

    headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

    headers.set("Authorization", jwtTokenProvider.createToken(account.username, authorities))


    val httpEntity = HttpEntity<String>(headers)



    val responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:$port/api/user/me",HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity, String::class.java )


    assertEquals(responseEntity.statusCode, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

But ErROR in logs:

`2020-06-06 23:24:51.989 DEBUG 26236 --- [o-auto-1-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}`

what am I doing wrong?(
did according to a similar rule: https://o7planning.org/ru/11647/spring-boot-restful-client-with-resttemplate-example

Comment: in header: Header:

Key: "Authorization"
Value: "AwesomeToken {user_token}" // (I get it from jwtTokenProvider.createToken(account.username, authorities)